# Replace a value in a select query conditionally where a value is 1, replace it with 0, if value in another table is 0

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables:

`OriginTable`:

```
ID | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday
1  | 1      | 1       | 2
```

`#ContrastTable`:

```
ID | MoTotal | TuTotal | WeTotal
1  | 6       | 0       | 32
```

I want to do this:

```
Select ot.Monday, ot.Tuesday, ot.Wednesday From OriginTable ot

| 1      | 1       | 2
```

But I want to edit the result set such that if a *Total* in the `ContrastTable` is 0, it will replace the value for that day in the `OriginTable` select with a `0`.

Some Crappy-SQL™ would look like this (this is just to demonstrate my intention, I'm aware this doesn't work):

```
Select ot.Monday, Replace(ot.Tuesday, ot.Tuesday, (ct.TuTotal) `[if ct.TuTotal is 0]`), ot.Wednesday From OriginTable ot
Inner Join #ContrastTable ct on ot.ID = ct.ID
```

Comment: I would use SIGN on the ContrastTable and multiply it against the OriginTable. I will work on a proper answer tomorrow if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IIF()` you can get the expected result:

```
Select ot.Monday, 
       --Replace(ot.Tuesday, ot.Tuesday, (ct.TuTotal) `[if ct.TuTotal is 0]`),
       IIF(ct.TuTotal = 0, ct.TuTotal, ot.Tuesday) AS Tuesday
       ot.Wednesday 
From OriginTable ot
Inner Join #ContrastTable ct on ot.ID = ct.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select ot.id
 , case when c.MoTotal = 0 then 0 else ot.Monday end as Monday 
 , case when c.TuTotal = 0 then 0 else ot.Tuesday end as Tuesday
 , case when c.WeTotal= 0 then 0 else ot.Wednesday end as Wednesday 
  From OriginTable ot 
 inner join #ContrastTable as c on ot.id=c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions:

```
select (case when ct.MoTotal = 0 then 0 else ot.Monday end) as Monday,
       (case when ct.TuTotal = 0 then 0 else ot.Tuesday end) as Tuesday,
       (case when ct.WeTotal = 0 then 0 else ot.Wednesday end) as Wednesday
from OriginTable ot left join
     #ContractTable ct
     on ct.id = ot.id;
```